# Dynamic Dropdown Menu PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, dynamic, menu, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to create a dynamic dropdown menu that populates by using Mysql and generates a dynamic link. I'm kind of new to both PHP and Mysql but I've got the menu working however I haven´t been able to insert children to the menu this is the code I have so far I've tried dozens of tutorials but none of them seem to work I would really appreciate your help

Thanks Again!

```
    <?php
    include_once('dbcon.php');
    $menuid = $_GET['id'];
    $menu_sql = "SELECT * FROM dyn_menu";
    $menu_query = mysql_query($menu_sql);
    $rsmenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_query);


 do {
?>
    <li><a href="../ambiental.php?menuID=<?php echo $rsmenu['id'];?> "><?php echo        
    $rsmenu ['label'];?></a></li>
    <?php
}
while ($rsmenu = mysql_fetch_assoc($menu_query));
?>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is?  Are you seeing an error?  Is any of the above code printing out correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to **only** select the menu_items that apply:

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
$menu_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['menu_id']);
$menu_sql = "SELECT d.id, d.menu_text FROM dyn_menu d WHERE d.menu_id = '$menu_id' ";
//don't forget the quotes !                                             ^        ^

if ($result = mysql_query($menu_sql) ) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    $item = htmlentities($row['menu_text']);
    $id = intval($row['id']);
  ?><li><a href="../ambiental.php?menuID=<?php 
    echo $id;
  ?> "><?php 
    echo $item; 
  ?></a></li><?php 
  } 
} else {
  echo "no menu_items for ".htmlentities($menu_id);
}
```

Always escaping input into an SQL statement using `mysql_real_escape_string` and don't forget the quotes.   (or suffer SQL-injections)
Always sanitize your output to screen using `htmlentities` (or suffer XSS).